# Fuzzy search a part of the whole text in Solr

Tags: solr, wildcard, fuzzy-search

I have the following field declaration for my Solr index:

```
<field name="description" type="text_ci" indexed="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
```

Field type:

```
<fieldType name="text_ci" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In this index I have documents, where description value is like "Accomodation in {city}" (they all have different cities)

I want to make a fuzzy search and when I enter misspelled `*acomodation*~2` for example to get results, but I find it difficult, because "accomodation" is just a part of the text.

I am thinking of using NGramFilter to tokenize the input, but I am not sure if this is the right way and how to implement it.

Do you know, what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or Edit Distance algorithm. To do a fuzzy search use the tilde, `"~"`, symbol at the end of a Single word Term.

I don't see a need of NGramFilter here.

`~` operator is used to run fuzzy searches.
You need to add `~` operator after every single term and can also specify edit distance which is optional after that as below.

```
{FIELD_NAME:TERM_1~{Edit_Distance}
```

Your request will look like below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/FuzzySearchExample/select?indent=on&q=desc:Samsu~&wt=json&fl=id,desc
```

I had the field type as below.

```
<fieldType name="text_ci" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I get the below response for `acomodation~2` or `acomodation~1`

[image: Screenshot od solr query page]

And I get the below response for `acomodation`.

[image: Screenshot of query page2]

Comment: But I also need the wildcard, because I don't get any hits if I just enter the query like so "description: acomodation~2".

Comment: That's because of the `KeywordTokenizer` which keeps the whole input as a single token. If you want each word to be searchable, use a different tokenizer - such as the `StandardTokenizer`

Comment: try by applying text general as the field type to your field

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but StandardTokenizer doesn't work either.

Comment: @PetarYakov : I have modified the answer. Please check.

Comment: I still get nothing. Why do you use StandardTokenizer only for the index and not for the query also?

Comment: because i want to create token in order to achieve the search...hence used the standardTokenizer at the time of indexing....I want the string as it is hence no used at query time....You can use the standardTokenizer at query time...no restriction...Use however it suits your requirement....After doing the changes in schema file...do a restart of solr server

Comment: It worked. I had to do a full import to update the data. Thanks man.